# Line of switches on a breadboard

Tags: switches, ground, breadboard, button

I'm connecting 8 switches on a breadboard, with a common ground (the already-connected line of the breadboard):

[image]

Problem: these switches are always on,  **like if the 2 pins on the common line make them pressed**.

I thought that a solution could be to rotate 90° the switches, but then they don't fit on the breadboard anymore (one cannot use the common horizontal line for ground anymore).

I can't believe there isn't a natural solution to connect 8 such switches on a breadboard.

**Is there a solution for this?**

[image]

Comment: Why do you find it so surprising that those little tactile buttons weren't made for breadboards? Breadboard use probably accounts for about 0.000001% of them ...

Comment: Ok @brhans. Breadboards looked so nice and perfect for everything, I thought maybe there's an easy solution that I didn't see :)

Comment: There is... get your pliers out and bend up one of the grounded pins.

Comment: Part number and data sheet link?

Comment: Instead of guessing, have you measured how the pins are connected and switched?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Simple breadboard solution :**  Get your pliers out and bend up one of the grounded pins.

Comment: This would bend the flat pins in the wrong direction and possibly break it,.

Comment: Na, they are pretty malleable @TonyStewart.EEsince'75. And if he breaks a couple...there is still a spare.

Comment: done that too... I was trying to suggest a more rigid adaptation for tactile  feel.

Answer (score 1):

1)  You failed to check which pins are common and bridged the switch to the supply rail

2) You were not aware that these tactile switches are metric pitch and the short lead gap is the contact pair is probably 4mm or 0.157" and the breadboard has 0.1" centers.

### Solution

Solder  resistor leads to the pins then trim to proper length to prevent protrusion thru the bottom.

These leads are plated round steel wire which is stiffer than copper wire and easily fits the sockets using 1/4W R's.

[image]

Note that the leads do not reach the holes.

- stretching the pins sideways must be done with care not to damage the structure.

Thus the tactile switch body will not be firmly seated against the board and may move every time it is used.

However putting resistor wires on the outside can position the wires so they conveniently fit over the holes. Using a solid spacer under the switch can support it so the body can sit tight on the board.

Or carefully mangle the leads

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just cut the diagonally opposite legs off, then it will work how you want.

Comment: Or do the unthinkable: look up the datasheet for the button.  (Not as much fun as cutting legs, though.)